# R Matching values in dataframe with repetitions

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am try to attach a column to a dataframe whose elements sholud be automatically compiled depending on the elements of another column. 
In this case I need to attach the coordinates of a particular place. There can be repetitions in the dataframe.
Here's an example:

I have a Dataframe

```
 Time    Adress 
13:00    Straight Ave.
13:45    Uphill Cr.
15:30    Narrow Rd.
15:45    Broad Way
16:35    Tiny Square
18:25    Broad Way
18:40    Uphill Cr.
19:20    Narrow Rd.
20:00    Dunkel Alley
```

And a coordinates Dataframe

```
Adress          Loc. Coord x   Loc. Coord y
Broad Way       10237871       89809209
Dunkel Alley    10236790       89883490
Narrow Rd.      10227398       89482378
Straight Ave.   10238700       89834782
Tiny Square     10237894       89803248
Uphill Cr.      10439002       89802380
```

And wolud like to attach the two local coordinates columns to the first dataframe in the right order. I have tried to use match but I think it doesn't allows repetitions, i.e. the two dataframes must have the same length. Anybody has an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "Adress")
```

Think this should work.

Comment: That worked, thank you!